# Random photo generation?

Tags: probability

Well, how to calculate such value?

Assume we took a picture (320x240px, 16 bit color) and want to know which chance of random generation it has. Exact this set of pixels, of course, to simplify our task.

If we talk in the probability theory terms, we should place `2^16` different colors in `320*240` positions (in other words, permute this color set with repetitions).

So my probability theory knowledge ends here. I don't know what to do further. Should it be calculated as `(2^16)^(320*240)` or `(2^16)*(320*240)` or maybe something else? And why so?

Comment: Are you aware that $(2^{16})^{(320\times240)} = 2^{(16\times 320 \times 240)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N = (2^{16})^{320\times 240} = 2^{16\times 320\times 240} = 2^{1228800}$ would be the right answer, you have $320\times 240$ pixels and $2^{16}$ different colors to choose from for each pixel. That makes a very large number of possible pictures, most looking horrible.

As Batman notes below, assuming that the images are drawn uniformly from all these possible images, the probability that you get a given one of these images would be $1/N$.

Comment: Thats the number of possible images. the probability is 1/that assuming the images are drawn uniformly. As a side note, in 16 bit color, normally you only have 12 bits used for colors and 4 used for alpha levels (transparency) or 15 bits used for colors and 1 bit used for alpha.